Is the co in components accidental?
We have vectors and covectors, domains and codomains, tangents and cotangents, and in general, in category theory, the prefix co reverses the direction of a morphism.
Is the co in component just an accident of the English language or does it makes sense within the convention of applying the prefix to mathematical objects?
It seems confusing to talk about components of vectors and components of covectors.

"component" is derived from the latin "componere", which means "to put together". It comes to English through Middle English and French. The "co" is not a modifying prefix, the way it is in the other words you mention. Not every English word that starts with the phoneme "co" is an instance of a duality.

My co-mment: this is a valid question, but more on language and not on mathematics.

It's a "com," not a "co." From etymonline:

1640s, "constituent part or element" (earlier "one of a group of persons," 1560s), from Latin componentem (nominative componens), present participle of componere "to put together, to collect a whole from several parts," from com "with, together" (see com-) + ponere "to place" (see position (n.)). Related: Componential.

The intended meaning is (I assume) that the components of a vector come together to make it up. This likely predates the use of "co" to refer to categorical dualities by at least decades, maybe centuries.

Johnstone points out somewhere that there are even more potentially confusing words deriving from Latin “cum (with)” which becomes “com” or even just “co” in English (see “costar”). The worst one is “cofinal”, for a subset of a poset that “ends along with” the whole poset—not by any means the dual notion of a “final” subset! This has caused minor disasters with generalizing terminology for this sort of sub-poset to cofinal/final/initial functors.
